# AWS Loadbalancer "OutOfService"

Tags: load-balancing, amazon-elb, prestashop-1.5

I recently set up an ELB for my apps instance. However i keep getting OutOfService error message.

After a quick check, i realized that my apps always redirects any HTTP request from:

1. xx-xxx-xx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com to mydomain.com
2. My EC2 Public IP to mydomain.com

It's just how the app behaves. Hence everytime ELB tries to ping at port :80 it always fails, since the app response with HTTP 301 redirection.

I wonder if there is a work around to mitigate this problem. Can anyone point me to the right direction.

By the way the web app i am talking about is Prestashop.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a "health check" route, dummying like `/test` that returns 200 if everything is ok on the instance. Tell the ELB Health Check to test that instead of `/`